# Separate drumkit into hands and feet in Musink music maker

Tags: notation, drums, software

I'm writing drum and percussion exercises in Musink music maker software. It's going well except when I write the hands and feet the notes 'join'.

[image: drums in Musink music maker]

I would like them to be separate. I read about [voice groups](https://wiki.musink.net/doku.php/project/voice-groups) but it seems to be the opposite of what I want.

How do I separate the hands and feet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look elsewhere in [Musink's help documentation](https://wiki.musink.net/doku.php/project/staves-and-voices) they show how you can add a second voice and write notes for your feet only in there. I've put the snare and feet together here but you can split them however you like:

[image: drums split into two voices]

When you convert to PDF it will overlay the two:

[image: published drums from musink]

FWIW using the voice groups will actually join the two voices as though you wrote them together - like you say, this is the opposite of your goal.

Comment: That looks about right! Why are the rests blue?

Comment: It's optional. Blue means they are set to be invisible in publishing to pdf. Search for publish visibility (Otherwise you would have rests and the drum fill, which is not standard notation.)